# Nginx for Wordpress in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, nginx, static, assets

I've the following Nginx configuration to run my Wordpress application. The Wordpress files are inside the wordpress folder that I created in the root directory.

> /var/www/webroot/wordpress

In the domain that I'll use to access the application I need to have one more path.

> example.com/wordpress/custompath

nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes 1;


error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;
}


http {

    #allows file uploads up to 8 megabytes
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    server_tokens off;
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    client_header_buffer_size 4k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    sendfile on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Websocket support
    #upstream websocket {
    #    server 127.0.0.1:<PORT>;
    #}
    server {

        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        #cookies default descomplica
        client_header_buffer_size 4k;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
        include /etc/nginx/aliases.conf;

        #location /ws {
        #    proxy_pass http://websocket;
        #    proxy_http_version 1.1;
        #    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        #    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        #}

        location /wordpress/custompath {

            root /var/www/webroot;
            index index.php /wordpress/index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;

            location ~ \.php$ {

                location ~ /\. {

                    deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off;
                }
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            }
        }

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {

            root html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}
        location ~ /\. {

            deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off;
        }
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
        location ~ \.php$ {

            location ~ /\. {

                deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off;
            }
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/webroot$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/webroot;
        }

    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

With this current setting all static give 404 error. I tried several modifications, but every time I had a different error. I'm not very familiar with nginx.

What do I need to adjust in the nginx configuration to have Wordpress running in my context?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067331/how-to-run-django-and-wordpress-using-nginx-and-gunicorn-at-the-same-domain/43067793#43067793).

Comment: I've checked it out, I tried to make a few changes based on the example of this link but had no success. I've updated my questions with my current nginx.conf

Comment: Just to be clear, the URI `//example.com/wordpress/custompath/index.php` should execute the script at `/var/www/webroot/wordpress/index.php` (that is without the *custompath* bit)?

Comment: Exactly! I currently run and manage to serve the pages. The problem is with the statics, I can not access it. I get an error from Wordpress itself saying that page does not exist, but it's not a page!