# nginx + wordpress in subfolder + debian configuration

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, fpm

In a subfolder on a domain I want to install a wordpress blog. I use nginx. The URL to access the blog should be like this: `example.com/blog`

site config looks as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/example.com/html; 
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;   
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location /blog {
                alias /var/www/example.comblog/html;
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ /blog/.+\.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

- The wordpress files reside in the folder
  `/var/www/example.comblog/html`. When accessing `example.com/blog`,
  the browser shows a 404 error.
- In `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` I adapted this: `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0`
- nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
- `/var/log/nginx/error.log` does not show anything of interest

**UPDATE 1:**

After setting error logging to debug, (among others) the following lines appear. Maybe this helps:

```
open index "/var/www/example.comblog/html/index.php"
internal redirect: "/blog/index.php?"
rewrite phase: 1
test location: "/blog"
test location: ~ "/blog/.+\.php$"
using configuration "/blog/.+\.php$"
http script var: "/blog/index.php"
trying to use file: "/blog/index.php" "/var/www/example.com/html/blog/index.php"
```

The internal redirect seems incorrect? And in the last line there should be `/var/www/example.comblog/html/blog/index.php` instead of `/var/www/example.com/html/blog/index.php`. I suspect this is the reason for the 404. Because the `index.php` does not exist at `/var/www/example.com/html/blog/index.php`.

**Update 2:**

Okay there seems to be a *[long standing issue with using alias together with try_files](https://serverfault.com/a/828579/305660)*.

Comment: Your php location needs to be nested into the aliased location - see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067331/how-to-run-django-and-wordpress-using-nginx-and-gunicorn-at-the-same-domain/43067793#43067793).