# How to add wordpress blogs to angular8 websites?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server, angular8, nginx-config

i have angualr 8 wbeiste called https://modernpackaging.in/ now i wanted to add the blog page for website for that i used the wordpres. My website is hosted on amazon ec2 Nginx server.
I have installed the wordpress at location **/var/www/** no i want that when i want to load wordpress blogs for this https://modernpackaging.in/blog path.

i added

```
location /blog/ {
                    # root /var/www/wordpress/;
                    index index.php;
            }
```

inside my nginx config file but does not working please help me out here.

Comment: Read [this article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/) first.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067331/how-to-run-django-and-wordpress-using-nginx-and-gunicorn-at-the-same-domain/43067793#43067793).

Comment: i have installed the wordrpess on inginx but getting 403 everytime see the url https://modernpackaging.in/blog/   this is my wordpress folder permssion drwxrwxrwx 5 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 29 18:58 wordpress and this is my nginx config  location ^~/blog/ {
      alias /var/www/wordpress;
      index index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }  @RichardSmith

Comment: i have installed the wordrpess on inginx but getting 403 everytime see the url https://modernpackaging.in/blog/   this is my wordpress folder permssion drwxrwxrwx 5 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 29 18:58 wordpress and this is my nginx config  location ^~/blog/ {
      alias /var/www/wordpress;
      index index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }  @IvanShatsky